# Error when installing Ubuntu (Input/output error)

Tags: server, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server as a single OS on an old PC I have lying around, however I am getting the error and upon checking the logs. I am getting the following error in the last line:

```
stdout: sfdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/output error
```

I have attached a photo of the logs.

[image: Logs]

Comment: Just after that error, type `lsblk  -ape7` (hit Enter) and copy that text if possible, paste into the text in your posting above, and mark it as "code".

Comment: Looks like a faulty HDD. How old is that "old pc"?

Comment: Can you run a **live** Linux light-weight desktop system (for example Lubuntu or Debian)? Then you can use Disks alias `gnome-disks` or `smartctl` to check the drive.